# CloudKit With CoreData Initial Sync On New Device

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit

I have an app that uses CloudKit to sync a private database data between multiple devices.  I am using CoreData for local persistence of the data.  When the user downloads my app on a new device, I am currently downloading all the records from CloudKit and performing a lot of processing to properly build the CoreData persistence on the new device. As the amount of records grows, the processing time will continue to grow.

I was thinking it would be more efficient to transfer a copy of CoreData from iCloud file storage to build the initial local persistence file on the new device. Is there a way to use CloudKit in conjunction with iCloud file storage to build the initial persistence file and then use CloudKit to maintain synchronization between devices after the initial sync?

All the tutorials I have seen use either CloudKit or iCloud file storage rather than a hybrid approach.

Comment: How much is "a lot of processing" and what are you doing with it? The first thing I'd try is optimizing that process to either not download so much data or not spend so much time dealing with it after download.

Comment: @TomHarrington The processing is mainly to build relationships in core data. I am downloading all the records then I have to build the relationships by finding the associated object IDs. There are a lot of relationships so it can take 30 seconds or so to process ~ 2500 records.